# Buildbot tutorial failure - worker can't connect to master

Tags: buildbot

I'm trying out buildbot, and following the tutorial. I successfully installed and started the master, as shown from the twistd.log partial file below.

```
2018-11-14 08:32:52-0600 [-] BuildMaster is running
2018-11-14 08:32:52-0600 [-] buildbotNetUsageData: sending 
{'installid': '38122a5be5d93ebdf0ef631a1584f36f418d12c0', 'versions': 
{'Python': '3.6.3', 'Buildbot': '1.5.0', 'Twisted': '18.9.0'}, 
'platform': {'platform': 'Darwin-18.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit', 'system': 
'Darwin', 'machine': 'x86_64', 'processor': 'i386', 
'python_implementation': 'CPython', 'version': 'Darwin Kernel Version 
18.2.0:', 'distro': '10.14.2'}, 'plugins': 
{'buildbot/worker/base/Worker': 1, 'buildbot/config/BuilderConfig': 1, 
'buildbot/schedulers/basic/SingleBranchScheduler': 1, 
'buildbot/schedulers/forcesched/ForceScheduler': 1, 
'buildbot/changes/gitpoller/GitPoller': 1, 
'buildbot/steps/source/git/Git': 1, 
'buildbot/steps/shell/ShellCommand': 1}, 'db': 'sqlite', 'mq': 
'simple', 'www_plugins': ['waterfall_view', 'console_view', 'grid_view']}
```

After installing and setting up the worker, the worker fails to connect to the master, and I'm also unable to load localhost:8010 as the tutorial indicates should be running. I've verified that I created the worker with the same worker name and password as the master.cfg file specifies. Any thoughts on what I missed?

A partial worker twistd.log is below:

```
2018-11-14 08:32:34-0600 [-] Connecting to localhost:9989
2018-11-14 08:32:34-0600 [Uninitialized] Connection to localhost:9989 failed: Connection Refused
2018-11-14 08:32:34-0600 [Uninitialized] <twisted.internet.tcp.Connector object at 0x10d8e6080> will retry in 62 seconds
2018-11-14 08:32:34-0600 [Uninitialized] Retry attempt 4/inf
2018-11-14 08:32:34-0600 [-] Stopping factory <buildbot_worker.pb.BotFactory object at 0x10d8d6c50>
2018-11-14 08:33:37-0600 [-] Starting factory <buildbot_worker.pb.BotFactory object at 0x10d8d6c50>
2018-11-14 08:33:37-0600 [-] Connecting to localhost:9989
2018-11-14 08:33:37-0600 [Uninitialized] Connection to localhost:9989 failed: Connection Refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try use **buildbot reconfig** (http://docs.buildbot.net/1.5.0/manual/cfg-intro.html?highlight=reconfig)
or **buildbot upgrade-master** (http://docs.buildbot.net/1.5.0/manual/cmdline.html?highlight=upgrade-master#)

Also, You can find a reference to **reconfig** in the Buildbot Quick Tour: (http://docs.buildbot.net/1.5.0/tutorial/tour.html)

You should use this after each changes in your Buildbot decision (workers, schedules, notifiers, factories, etc...)

Comment: Thank you. I've tried all three suggestions, and I still have the exact same problem. The worker connection is refused, as is localhost:8010.